# Active Facebook access token iOS error

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook with my iOS app but am running into this snag.

When I first ran this code it worked perfectly but it seems like something in the facebook cache is causing this error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I use these 2 functions to attempt to upload a photo:

```
+(BOOL)logInAndPostImage:(UIImage*)image andMessage:(NSString*)message {

    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    return [FBSession  openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                                 allowLoginUI:YES
                                            completionHandler:
            ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                    state:state
                                    error:error];
                if(error) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Problem connecting with Facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                } else {
                    [self postImage:image andMessage:message];
                }
            }];
}

+(void)postImage:(UIImage*)image andMessage:(NSString*)message
{

    NSLog(@" Access Token Description: %@",[[FBSession activeSession] accessToken].description);

    [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:image completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                        message:@"Your update has been posted to Facebook!"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Sweet!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                        message:@"Yikes! Facebook had an error.  Please try again!"
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

    }];
}
```

When I query for the description of the active token description, its actually null. So I guess while `FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` doesn't return with an error, I'm not generating a token?

Any suggestions as to how I can further debug this error? I have followed all the additional setup outlined by the Facebook Developer page.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your session is actually not opened. You shouldn't call

```
[self postImage:image andMessage:message];
```

Unless there's no error and

```
(state == FBSessionStateOpen)
```

To debug this further, just take a look at the value of the "state" variable and see what it is.

Another thing to be aware of is, if this is the very first time the user is logging into your app, you can't ask for publish/write permissions. You must ask for read permissions initially and then later on, in context, request publish permissions. If you ask for publish permissions initially, you should get an error. As you're not getting an error, that may not be the case.